# Wordpress Themify Responsiveness Issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I am running a WordPress site using the Themify Basic theme. When I enable the responsive feature, the social links cover my logo and current posts appear before my content, which is seriously hurting my bounce rate.

If I turn it off, it looks awesome, but doesn't pass google mobile friendly tests. Any fix recommendations?

To my understanding this is a common issue with responsive themes.

(I am not super code savvy)

[with responsive](http://i126.photobucket.com/albums/p96/penislessjesus_photos/shouldnotbe.png)

[without responsive](http://i126.photobucket.com/albums/p96/penislessjesus_photos/shouldbe.jpg)

Comment: Without access to your code or the site there is no way to answer this question. `To my understanding this is a common issue with responsive themes` The general issue may be common, but the actual problem is unique to your implementation.

Comment: Yes I see you have used media screen below 380px i guess with other style to overcome. You would need to right inorder to display the social icons below the logo and then search. So need to change the css from that width.

Comment: I ended up hiring a coder :)